# Customize Search in ActionBar

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar

I am using search inside ActionBar. Now I am able to do this as per documents and example says, But my requirement is little different. Current Search function looks like that:
[image]

But I want to apply like this:

[image]

ie. When user clicks on search icon.. separate layout should be open as last image. And also i want this in all screen. I followed this link for adding search [link](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html#create-sc) and did successfully default search.

Comment: Do you really need to have 'Home' in the centre?

Comment: @MacaronLover: Nope... home doesn't matter...

Comment: It's not a good idea to have more than one search icon present in the user's view as it would cause confusion.

Comment: yup @MacaronLover... but client needs that :p.. I tried to convince but he wants that only :)

Comment: Can't help you there unfortunately

Comment: No probs.. But can you tell me if it is possible or not?? @MacaronLover

Comment: It is possible but I've not seen any code like that on the Internet